# How do I put extracted folder 'Cleanto' on my website root so that the path should look like http://yourwebsite/cleanto/index.php

Tags: server, files, root, paths

How do I do step 3? I am not tech savvy, so please make it simple.

Way to Installation  We are trying to make the installation process more easy and handy so that user can install our system in his existing system with easy steps. We are also providing you the best ever installing service to integrate our application with your existing system if you have.

Step by Step guide for installation:

0. Buy the system from us and just follow the below steps
1. Take backup of your website for precaution
2. Unzip `Cleanto.zip` file you got with downloaded pack
3. You have to put extracted folder `Cleanto` on your website root so that the path should look like:

   ```
   http://yourwebsite/cleanto/index.php
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Do Not put Cleanto files on your root folder as it has `index.php` and it can overwrite your website files, which can be very problematic.</sup>
4. Just open `http://yourdomain.com/cleanto`
5. You will now see the below Cleanto installer. "Fresh Install" and then click on "Start Install" button

Answer (score 1):

As you have not specified which version of Ubuntu you're using, nor whether you are using Apache or nginx, I am going to assume the following:

- you are running Ubuntu Server 18.04 or newer
- you are running Apache 2.4 or newer
- you have a properly functional PHP installation
- your Apache root directory is located in `/var/www/html` and you have not created any virtual hosts
- you have `Cleanto.zip` located in your home directory on the server

With this in mind, you can do the following:

0. Really ensure you have a proper backup of your site by making a `tar` file:

   ```
   sudo tar -cvf backup_$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).tar /var/www/html/*
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** This will create a file like `backup_2021-12-23.tar` in the current directory.</sup>
1. Create a directory for your appointment booking software:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /var/www/html/cleanto
   ```

   <sup>**IMPORTANT:** If your Apache root directory is not `html`, be sure to change it to the correct directory.</sup>
2. Move to the new directory and unzip the files:

   ```
   cd /var/www/html/cleanto
   unzip ~/Cleanto.zip .
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** If the `Cleanto.zip` file is *not* located in your home directory (eg: `/home/ubuntu/`), then change `~` to the full path to the file.</sup>
3. Ensure Apache owns the files:

   ```
   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data *
   ```
4. There is no step 4. You're done and can move on to the next part of the installation process.

**Note:** If you find that unzipping the `Cleanto.zip` file has created another `cleanto` directory in the directory you just created, move those files to the proper location like this:

```
sudo cp /var/www/html/cleanto/cleanto/* /var/www/html/cleanto
```

If any of the five assumptions at the start of this answer are incorrect, then the solution may not work for you. If this is the case, you will want to edit your question to include more specific details about your server and your Apache installation.